# Is it possible to troubleshoot distinct JS files in the Browser when using Browserify?

Tags: javascript, browserify

I am used to working with JavaScript files the old way in which every JS file has its own  element. For example:

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
<script src="bar.js"></script>
```

The good thing about the old method is in Chrome Dev Tools I can analyze a particular JS file. For example, if an error happens I know to look in bar.js for example. Even in production because we don't bundle.

I am researching using Browserify and I cannot find how to troubleshoot a single JS file that was bundled using Browserify.

Question: Is it possible to troubleshoot distinct JS files in the Browser when using Browserify? If yes, then how?

Comment: There's a section in the browserify handbook that explains how to generate sourcemaps to help with debugging: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#development

Comment: @KevinB, the Browserify build tool is not what you think. You write JavaScript in a node flavor and it compiles all of the JS files into a single JS file that the Browser understands. Thus, there is no "Dev" opportunity to troubleshoot JS files separately.

Comment: @KevinB, I read this section. That's not what I mean. I'm going to edit my question to be more precise.

Comment: The source mapping is the only option, due to the way browserify compiles the code. Or, you could go with something other than browserify of course.

Comment: @KevinB, so your answer to my question is NO. I hope that this is not the case. I'll wait some more.

Comment: The issue stems from the fact that when using browserify, all of the files are compiled to a single file, making it impossible to debug them separately from the browser console other than through what is available with source mapping.

Comment: @SBel you should actually try using a sourcemap. It will do pretty much exactly what you want, and takes practically no effort to set up

Comment: @Bojangles, I will try the sourcemap and get back to you.

Comment: @Bojangles, you're right: mapping file is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is yes. Here are the details. Suppose you have 2 JS files:

```
// main.js
var unique = require('uniq');
var foo = require('./foo.js');

var data = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6];

console.log(foo(7));
console.log("works!");

console.log(unique(data));
```

and

```
// foo.js
module.exports = function (n) { return n * 111 }
```

Use the following command to generate the bundled file and its mapping file:

```
browserify main.js --debug | exorcist bundle.js.map > bundle.js
```

In Dev Tools you'll see this (as you can see the 2 files are debuggable):

[image]